# Storing encrypted password in session vs url

Tags: asp.net, security, session, authentication

From a security point of view does it make any difference where an encrypted password is stored for logging in? I was thinking of having something like the following:

```
Password = 123456
Encrypted = 21909qujea8je2829dj92

url = selectaccount.aspx?p=21909qujea8je2829dj92&email=someemail@somewhere.com

or 

Session["encryptedPassword"] = 21909qujea8je2829dj92
Session["LoginEmail] = someemail@somewhere.com
```

Comment: Why are you storing the password? Why don't you do a check that the password is valid, and then store the result of that check in session state?

Comment: I need to log in the user with that password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to store the password in either of these locations. Once the user has authenticated, their cookie should maintain their identity. The modern built-in asp.net implementations of authentication are secure and flexible. What reason do you have to re-invent the wheel?

PS - Hashing instead of encryption is considered best practice for dealing with passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it on server (in session) and dont make it public via querystring. Once a user has entered his password it should not be sent back to him (encrypted or not) so that he can carry it to the next page.